# Are Particles Excitations in Fields?

Tags: particle-physics, field-theory

If particles are excitations of fields: how does the field record the spin of a particular particle?

There is no space to record the spin states of two particles, of opposite spin, in the field.

Comment: "Particle" and "field" are mathematical idealizations of the phenomena we see. We successfully *model* particles as field excitations.

Comment: Only because Nature is forgiving: you can ignore Isospin and still produce an accurate prediction.

Comment: @talanumi Models are models. History suggests that none of them are "correct". Isospin is just another mathematical idealization.

Answer (score 1):

The Dirac equation describes the coupled evolution of *four* fields, which are identified experimentally as the two spin states of a spin-half particle and its antiparticle. The idea that spin is an "extra property" of a particle that can be tacked on at the end is a nonrelativistic approximation; spinors arise naturally when relativistic interactions with the electromagnetic field are included.

There is just one (set of) spinor field(s) describing the coupled evolution of electrons and positrons everywhere in spacetime. It's possible for this field to contain multiple particle-like excitations. Distinguishing the "valence electrons" from the "core electrons" of an atom is likewise a nonrelativistic approximation.

The evolution of isospinors, such as the isospinor describing the electron, its neutrino, and their antiparticles, is similar in spirit to the Dirac equation. Rotations in isospin space, corresponding to transitions between an electron and its neutrino, are governed by an interaction field called the "charged current"; we are able to distinguish between electrons and neutrinos because the charged current interaction is much weaker than the electromagnetic interaction.

Comment: Where is Weak Isospin recorded then, or when there are three or more particles where are all the spins recorded?

Comment: I've updated the answer to address your comment.

Comment: So you can compute with for example <1/2, 1/2| as one particle and <1/4, 1/2| as another, but where are these spinors recorded? Is Isospin therefore recorded on paper by elements of another equation? Where in the field is it recorded?

Comment: If all the field records are probabilities and probability in one field means a spin up particle while probability in another field means spin down, then we would need a field for every possible quantum number of a particle. This is untenable.

Comment: How is this going to work for infinitely many energy values?

Comment: I don't have the skill to write the textbook chapter about the Dirac equation which would answer your questions — much less the corresponding chapter(s) about the Standard Model Lagrangian, which describes the behavior of weak isospin. Thinking the model is untenable is a fairly common step along the path to understanding what the model does and doesn't predict; the experimental predictions it *does* make have been extraordinarily successful.

Answer (score -1):

A field without particles or with only one particle is a theoretical construct and has no additional value. Only the interaction between particles makes a real field.

For electrons two states can be distinguished:

1. between two electrons there are two interactions: an electric interaction and a magnetic interaction. In the unbound state the range of the electric field is predominant and the electrons repel each other.
2. differently in the atom. There the electric field of the electron is bound by the field of the proton and the electrons "sit" close together. The magnetic dipoles of the electrons now align each other. Described by Pauli as the spin exclusion principle.

TL;DR
One should recall the history of the discovery of spin. At that time it was about the fine splitting of spectral lines in an external magnetic field, which expanded the atomic model by a spin quantum number.

Around the same time it was discovered that electrons are also magnetic dipoles. Unfortunately, the researchers were not allowed to recognize the inter-insian magnetic dipole as an equal property of the electron next to its electric charge, and explanations of the rotation were used to help.
TL;DR

> There is no space to record the spin states of two particles, of opposite spin, in the field.

Under the influence of an external magnetic field, you simply rotate the spin of free electrons parallel to the external field.

Comment: You didn't read my comments. You imply the spin of the electrons are recorded in a magnetic field, but what if there is no magnetic field?

Comment: When there is no external magnetic field, the electron is still a magnetic dipole and a charge. See the NIST values for both quantities of the electron.

Comment: Then where are the magnitude and direction of the magnetic field stored? The electron field can only store the probability of the magnetic field being a certain size.

Comment: Not to mention the direction.

Comment: Actually, the electromagnetic field can only record the probability of a photon being at a certain position.

Comment: This can only be true if the photon carries information (2 vectors and other quantum numbers).

Comment: And this information could vary in time.